# Objective C - can a segue be triggered with a touch of an ImageView or an Image?

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective C. I have been attempting to trigger a segue by a tap on an image view. I get no response. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set `userInteractionEnabled` to YES on your image view.
2. Set an identifier for your segue in the Interface Builder.
3. Add a tap gesture recognizer to your image view.
4. Perform the segue from the tap handler.

Here's some code to get you started.

> ```
> imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
> UITapGestureRecignizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecignizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTapImageView:)];
> [imageView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
>
>
> - (void)onTapImageView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
> {
>      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:self];
> }
> ```